# Does a SELECT COUNT(*) on a PostgreSQL table lock it?

Tags: postgresql, locking, row

Does performing a SELECT COUNT(*) on a PostgreSQL table lock it? If so is there a way around it to behave like WITH (nolock) in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A SELECT never locks a table in Postgres.

Or more precisely: it only takes a very weak shared lock that prevents DDL on the table.

In Postgres, readers never block writers and writers never block readers.

Answer (score 1):

Every type of access to a table takes a lock. So Yes, it does take a lock. But it looks like you have a different question because a question like this only pops up when you have a problem. But we don't know what problem that is.

All the different types of locks and how they interact with each other, can be found in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html). In most cases you don't have any issues with concurrency. You can have dozens of concurrent SELECT statements on the same table without any locking issues.